# Create new form section onSubmit form trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm very new to apps script and have been trying to create a new form section that is displayed after the previous section is submitted. Or to open a new form...

I have a feeling my issue may be because the form has already been submitted and it is not possible to add to it (via apps script) and then display this.

A quick description of my form: it is a booking form, where the user can book for between 1 and 12 people (and has to be identified as being part of the same group). After the user has entered the 'How many are you booking for?' value, I want to auto-generate the fields required for them to complete i.e. for 1 person or 12 people.

So I think my question is: is it possible to programmatically add to an active form as it is being completed? And could someone point me in the right direction as to how to do this or to a similar example.

I've read lots of the help guidance and followed examples but I can't seem to find an example which actually does this 'on the fly'.

I'm using a linked spreadsheet to store responses.

Comment: Please take the [tour], and read [ask].

Comment: You can't add to a form *in situ*. You'll have to implement the logic in forms, with prepared pages and go to the right page based on the number of people input, or go entirely script-based, and use a combination of HtmlService and SpreadsheetApp. For the prepared pages, you'd want to start at the max person and supply details for one person per page (to avoid having a response column created for each person input on each page), and the next page would decrease. I.e., 12 people -> 12 -> 11 -> 10 ... 1,  6 people -> 6 -> 5 -> .... 1.
Or just a single page and allow empty values.